# field extension $F(x)=F(x^2)$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, field-theory, modules

Let $x$ be algebraic over $F$ such that the field extension $F(x):F$ satisfies $[F(x):F]$ odd. Then prove $[F(x):F]=[F(x^2):F]$ hence $F(x)=F(x^2)$. How to prove?

I only obtained the proof for the case $x^{2m+1}=1$. How to prove for a general polynomial $p(x)$ of odd degree such that $p(x)=0$?

Answer (score 0):

If $F(x^2)$ is not $F(x)$ then $[F(x) : F(x^2)] = 2$, and $[F(x) : F] = [F(x) : F(x^2)] [F(x^2) : F]$ is even.

Comment: please try giving some hints first and then help the OP to go through the problem... I am not saying this should be done like this but I am saying this is how i was taken care by Users of this forum when i was new to this and that helped me a lot...