# Show that $F(a) = F(a^{2})$ knowing that $F(a)$ has odd degree.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, extension-field

> If $K$ is field extension of $F$ and if $a \in K$ such that $[F(a):F]$ is odd, show that $F(a) = F(a^{2})$. Given an example to show that this can be false if the degree of $F(a)$ over $F$ is even.

I know that $F(a^{2}) \subseteq F(a)$ and $[F(a):F] = [F(a):F(a^{2})][F(a^{2}):F]$. I know too that if $[K:F] = p$ with $p$ prime, so there are no intermediate fields between $K$ and $F$. Any hints?

Comment: This has been asked many times. Here are some more duplicates: [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/595008/field-extension-fx-fx2?noredirect=1&lq=1), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/231085/how-do-i-prove-fa-fa2), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1325329/suppose-f-is-a-field-and-the-irreducible-polynomial-over-f-of-x-is-of-odd?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 4):

**Hint :** First prove that $[F(a):F(a^2)]\leq 2$, and then prove that it can't be equal to $2$.

Answer (score 3):

In $F(a^2)[X]$ consider the polynomial of degree $2$, $P(X)=X^2-a^2$.

$a\in F(a)\supset F(a^2)$ is such that $P(a)=0$. So the degree of the extension is at most $2$. In other words $[F(a):F(a^2)]\in \{1,2\}$.

Because $[F(a):F]=[F(a):F(a^2][F(a^2):F]$, if $[F(a):F]$ is odd then $[F(a):F(a^2)]=1$ and this means $F(a)=F(a^2)$.

The counterexample is obvious. Consider $F=\Bbb{Q}$ and $a=\sqrt{2}$